# Proof that the event that the series $\sum\limits_nX_n$ converges is in the tail sigma-field

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is probably very stupid question, but I'm stuck. Suppose that $(X_n)_n$ is a sequence of independent random variables. Let $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_n)$. I am trying to proof that

$\left\lbrace\omega\colon\sum_n X_n(\omega) < \infty\right\rbrace$

is a tail event. I suppose, that it should easily follow from the fact, that

$\left\lbrace\omega\colon\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} X_k(\omega) < \infty\right\rbrace\in\sigma(\mathcal{F}_n, \mathcal{F}_{n+1}, \ldots)$.

My problem is, I can't proof the last one. It makes me feel so stupid :(

Comment: So, the question is why $\left\lbrace\omega\colon\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} X_k(\omega) < \infty\right\rbrace\in\sigma(X_k\,;\,k\ge n)$?

Comment: yes, that is my question

Comment: But you noted that the event in my comment depends only on $X_k$ for $k\ge n$, right? So...

Comment: Can somebody please give me a hint how to do this using measure theory?

Comment: [I did](https://youtu.be/HqIGiVLOY4E?t=28s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it step by step.

1. $X_n$ is $\sigma(X_n)$-measurable for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_n)$, this is equivalent to saying that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable.
2. Since $\mathcal{F}_n \subseteq \mathcal{G}_n := \sigma(\mathcal{F}_n,\mathcal{F}_{n+1},\ldots)$, this implies that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{G}_n$-measurable.
3. The sum $$\sum_{k=n}^N X_k$$ is, by step 2, $\mathcal{G}_n$-measurable as a finite sum of $\mathcal{G}_n$-measurable random variables.
4. The limit (provided it exists) $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} X_k = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^N X_k$$ is $\mathcal{G}_n$-measurable as pointwise limit of $\mathcal{G}_n$-measurable random variables.

Comment: @saz so the limit is measurable if it exists for each $\omega$. Could you please explain how does this imply that the set $\left\lbrace\omega\colon\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} X_k(\omega) < \infty\right\rbrace$ is measurable? I think we must take $g = \limsup \sum_{k=n}^N X_k$ (which will be measurable) and then the set above is the preimage $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @Goodnighyn Well, if the limit exists for all $\omega$, then it doesn't make any differences whether you use $\liminf$, $\limsup$ or $\lim$.

Comment: @saz that's true, but we do not know if it exists for all $\omega$. Moreover, even when it is $\infty$ for some $\omega$ the statement still holds.

Comment: @Goodnighyn In this case it depends pretty much on what you really want to prove. If you want to prove that $$\{\omega; \limsup_N \sum_{n=1}^N X_n(\omega) < \infty\}$$ is a tail event, then you can proceed as suggested in your comment. It is, however, also possible to show that the set $$\{\omega; \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n(\omega) \, \, \text{exists}\}$$ is a tail event (then you have to use a slightly different reasoning).

Comment: @saz Sorry, probably I misunderstand something. The OP wanted to prove that $F = \{ \omega: \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n(\omega) \, \, \text{exists} \} = \{\omega: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n(\omega) < \infty \}$ is a tail event. I say that this set is just the preimage $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, where $g = \limsup \sum_{k=n}^N X_k$ is a measurable function (always), so $F$ is measurable and hence a tail event. Am I correct? 
However, I do not understand how the fact that " **if** the limit exists, then the function is measurable" implies the measurability of $F$.

Comment: @Goodnighyn The OP didn't appear to care about the existence of the limit and therefore I just assumed that it exists. Note that "$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n$ exists" and "$\sum_{n \geq 1} X_n<\infty$" are two statements which are not equivalent (except we are a) talking about non-negative random variables or b) use the second statement as a sloppy notation for the first one). Now back to your question: If you define $g = \limsup_N \sum_{k=n}^N X_k$, then,in general, $F \neq g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ (finiteness of the limsup does not imply convergence of the series).

Comment: @saz aa.. yes, sorry, I implicitly assumed, that the random variables are non-negative.

Comment: Define $$h := \liminf_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^N X_k$$ then $h$ is also measurable and $$F = g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \cap h^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \cap \{g=h\}$$

Comment: @saz got it! thank you

Comment: @Goodnighyn You are welcome.